# all tableCells in different sections got selected of same row (using NSIndexPath)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I tried to create a simple checklist style tableView by following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([_selectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [_selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [_selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

However, when I select the first item and scroll, I found out ALL first items in the same section has the checkMark besides it. Doesn't NSIndexPath contain both row and section? What made all items got selected here? :(

Thanks!

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
}

if ([_selectedRows containsObject: indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

ABRecordRef selectedFriend = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(_allFriends, [indexPath row]);
NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(selectedFriend, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(selectedFriend, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Post your -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath code too..

Comment: what's `_selectedRows`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of cell reusage, you also have to remove the checkmark accessory if necessary (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
if ([_selectedRows containsObject: indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the accessory to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` for the non-selected rows since dequeued rows will keep their accessory.

```
// put this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method
if ([_selectedRows containsObject: indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```